# Повторяющиеся поля комментирования

Tags: php

Наверно мне сложно выразить свои мысли так как я не профессионал.
В базе данных есть продукты. Их нужно вывести на страницу. Я уже вывел, списком, типа ряд постов только в моем случае это только заголовки. Это понятно?
Нужно сделать систему комментирования этих постов прямо в этом списке, не заходя на страницу отдельного поста. Мой список выводится циклом foreach и я просто взял и вставил форму добавления комментария в этот foreach. У меня получился этакий список названий с полями добавления комментариев. Написал логику, вроде сам процесс комментирования работает. Но, срабатывает форма добавления комментария только первого заголовка, даже когда я комментирую второй или третий заголовок. Как сделать чтобы срабатывало именно нужное поле.

Помогите пожалуйста!
Вот контроллер:

```
function addcomraitAction() {
    if (! empty($_POST['content'])) {
    $content = isset($_POST['content']) ? $_POST['content'] : null;
    $content = htmlspecialchars($content);

    $user_id = isset($_POST['user_id']) ? $_REQUEST['user_id'] : null;
    $user_id = intval($user_id);

    $product_id = isset($_POST['product_id']) ? $_REQUEST['product_id'] : null;
    $product_id = intval($product_id);
    } else {
        return false;
    }


    $result = insertComment($content, $user_id, $product_id);

if ($result) {
        $resData['success'] = 1;
        $resData['message'] = 'Комментарий добавлен';
    }else{
        $resData['success'] = 0;
        $resData['message'] = 'Ошибка добавления комментария';
    }
    echo json_encode($resData);
    return;
}
```

А вот так я вывожу на страницу:

```
{foreach $products as $item name=product}
    <h2><a href="/product/page/{$item['id']}/">{$item['product']}</a></h2>
    <div id="blockNewComment">
    <form name="comment" action="" method="post">
        <p>
            <label>Комментарий:</label>
            <br />
            <textarea id="newContentComm" required name="content" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input id="newProductId" type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{$item['id']}" />
            <input id="newUserId" type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{$authUser['id']}" />
            <input type="submit" onclick="newComment();" value="Отправить" />
        </p>
    </form>
    </div>
{/foreach}
```

Ajax:

```
function newComment() {
    var content = $('#newContentComm').val();
    var product_id   = $('#newProductId').val();
    var user_id      = $('#newUserId').val();

    var postData = {content: content, product_id: product_id, user_id: user_id};

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        url: "/product/addcomrait/",
        data: postData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data['message']);
            if(data['success']) {
                $('#newContentComm').val('');
                $('#newProductId').val('');
                $('#newUserId').val('');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Вот вы пишете `$('#newProductId').val();`. Как по вашему скрипт должен догадаться значение от какого элемента ему нужно взять? Не говоря уже о том, что `id` на то и `id` чтобы быть уникальным в пределах страницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый вечер. Ваша проблема в том, что форм для комментариев много (для каждого поста своя, а вот у полей ввода один и тот же id. Когда вы пишете `$('#newContentComm').val();` всегда берется значение из первого элемента у которого такой id. По этой причине всегда срабатывает только форма от первого коммента. Исправить это можно несколькими способами. 
1. Добавить в id полей ввода id товара, чтобы получалось что-то вроде `newContentComm_31415`

2. Получать значения полей ввода исходя из DOM структуры

Остановимся подробнее на первом варианте.

Вывод вашей страницы поменяется так:

```
{foreach $products as $item name=product
<h2><a href="/product/page/{$item['id']}/">{$item['product']}</a></h2>
<div id="blockNewComment"> 
  <form name="comment" action="" method="post"> 
    <p>
      <label>Комментарий:</label> <br />
      <textarea id="newContentComm{$item['id']}" required name="content" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p> 
      <input id="newUserId" type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{$authUser['id']}" />
      <input type="submit" onclick="newComment({$item['id']});" value="Отправить" /> 
    </p>
  </form> 
</div>
{/foreach}
```

Тогда соответственно js код поменяется так:

```
function newComment(id) { 
  var content = $('#newContentComm'+id).val();
  var user_id = $('#newUserId').val(); 
  var postData = {content: content, product_id: id, user_id: user_id}; 
  $.ajax({ type: 'POST', async: false, 
    url: "/product/addcomrait/", data: postData, dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data){
     alert(data['message']); 
     if(data['success']) { 
       $('#newContentComm'+id).val(''); } } }); }
```

Прошу прощение за форматирование кода. Пишу с телефона, не очень удобно тут писать его)

Что изменилось: теперь функция добавления комментария принимает на вход id товара к которому отправляется комментарий. Исходя из id берется значение из нужного textarea. user_id не дублировал, т.к. полагаю во всех формах значение этого поля одинаковое. Ну и поменялся обработчик onclick, чтобы в функцию передавался id товара.

Comment: I got it! Огромное спасибо Никита! Я просто незнаю js, поэтому туплю наверно.